how to resolve php-fpm 502 bad gateway error
I am new to Docker and created an image using images nginx:alpine and php:fpm-alpine (follwed this article).
I went through different answers here but could not understand.
I didnt find  /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and seems that I am missing something basic. These are two containers and connected them via internal network bridge. Here is my docker-compose.yml file
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
  php:
    image: php:fpm-alpine
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge

Now, I composed up this yml file and can see containers up and running.
I saved, shut down the containers and loaded the php image and then tried to access the index page, I get 502 bad gateway error.
this is default.conf file where I am configuring the port
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params; 
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

docker-compose.yml file for the loaded image.
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: php_with_nginx_nginx:latest
    ports: 
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
  php:
    image: phpnginxload:latest
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge

When checked logs, there is no php service in the container
7020:~/php_with_nginx$ docker exec -it php_with_nginx_php_1 sh
/ # netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:38961        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:33901        0.0.0.0:*                    

there is no port 9000 here...
/usr/sbin # php-fpm -F
sh: php-fpm: not found
/usr/sbin # php -v
sh: php: not found
/usr/sbin # 

Folder structure:
- php_with_nginx
-- data
--- index.php
- logs
--nginx
 --access.log
 --error.log
--php.log
- nginx
-- default.conf
-- Dockerfile
-- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- docker-compose-save.yml

any pointers would be highly appreciated.

502 indicates that nginx is receiving the request but cannot pass it to the upstream which in this case, should be a php-fpm process exposed on 9000 that you're directing to the php container. If you docker exec -it -u root into the php container and run ps -aef --forest are there any php-fpm processes running? If there isn't, you need to start them which is probably better done with a custom build in a  Dockerfile Not entirely sure why you need nginx twice (based on the image name)

PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
    7 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www
    8 www-data  0:00 php-fpm: pool www```
process is running though..

I'm not too sure on your nginx configuration, this is one I open sourced for laravel - you could try this and see if its your nginx configuration causing the issue - https://github.com/Kyle-Jeynes/Laravel-Dockerized/blob/main/laravel/nginx.conf (ofc replacing your container name)

This is my config file
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params; 
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}```
this is dockerfile
```FROM nginx:alpine
ADD nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d```

What does your /var/log/nginx/error.log have in it? Your Nginx config doesn't look complete to me

[error] 31#31: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: , request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.25.0.2:9000", host: "localhost:8080".
